# Python giving me long strings in a text document

Tags: python, file-io, edit, bitcoin

In my code I have python opening a text document and printing a HTML document in to it.
by doing so it gives me a long sentence with `";"` in it

Example of text in the text document

```
Total:0.01358324;BTC:0.00000000;LTC:0.00000001;BC:0.00000000;NMC:0.00000000;DOGE:63.71131428;NAUT:0.00017886;DRK:0.00000000;VTC:0.00013866;FTC:0.00000000;CURE:0.00025881;PPC:0.00000000;CHARITY:0.00000000;GHS:0.00003646;GHSOCT:0.00000000;GHSAUG:0.00000000;SCRYPT:200.09600305
```

How would I write or edit the file so every `";"` forces a new line. I currently use this line to write a file called file.

```
file.write(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Are you reading and writing the same file? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with a newline char.

```
 file.write(response.read().decode('utf-8').replace(";","\n"))

In [72]: line = "Total:0.01358324;BTC:0.00000000;LTC:0.00000001;BC:0.00000000;NMC:0.00000000;DOGE:63.71131428;NAUT:0.00017886;DRK:0.00000000;VTC:0.00013866;FTC:0.00000000;CURE:0.00025881;PPC:0.00000000;CHARITY:0.00000000;GHS:0.00003646;GHSOCT:0.00000000;GHSAUG:0.00000000;SCRYPT:200.09600305"

In [73]: print (line.replace(";","\n"))
Total:0.01358324
BTC:0.00000000
LTC:0.00000001
BC:0.00000000
NMC:0.00000000
DOGE:63.71131428
NAUT:0.00017886
DRK:0.00000000
VTC:0.00013866
FTC:0.00000000
CURE:0.00025881
PPC:0.00000000
CHARITY:0.00000000
GHS:0.00003646
GHSOCT:0.00000000
GHSAUG:0.00000000
SCRYPT:200.09600305
```

Comment: Thank you. you're way worked the first time. I just picked up Python and trying to do some advance coding with a exchange trading bot.

Answer (score 1):

You can split on `;` and use the following:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as inp, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    data = inp.read().decode('utf-8').split(";")
    for line in data:
        out.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Comment: using split feels "cleaner" than using replace to me.

Comment: I'm only doing this so the program it self looks clean in the command line. I just wanted it to list out the 15 items with the lest amount of code and the replace metheod looked simple

Comment: @user3897196 that's alright. If the other answer is what you wanted, then go with it. Don't forget to accept an answer.